# Remove the existing string and append a new string for that string

Tags: swift, string, swift3, uikit

I have a video URL like this

```
urldomain.com/livestream_id/PLAYER_WIDTH&PLAYER_HEIGHT&IDFA_ID&DEVICE_ID
```

If the video URL contains the `PLAYER_WIDTH&PLAYER_HEIGHT` so I have to replace this string with this `&sd=1960*1080`, and if it does not contain `IDFA_ID` so I have to remove this from the URL, and if this contains `DEVICE_ID` so I have to replace DEVICE_ID with this `device_id="myDeviceid"`.

so my final URL looks like this

```
urldomain.com/livestream_id/?sd=1960*1080&deviceId="myDeviceid"
```

can anyone tell me how can I do this.

Comment: you could look at these examples and explanations:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

There are examples of how to insert and remove strings and characters,
 plus a section on substring.

Comment: I have multiple parameters can I use a dictionary for this or u have any other idea?

Comment: Would it be possible in your use case to break the string up into components? Then you can run functions on video player size and the device id. It might look something like: let url = "urldomain.com/livestream_id\(getPlayerSize()&\(getDeviceID()))". Then each one of those functions can return the appropriate string if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

No need to replace substrings in your string. You should use `URLComponents` to compose your `URL`. This way you don't have also to manually percent encode your string.

```
var components = URLComponents()
let scheme = "https"
let host = "urldomain.com"
let path = "/livestream_id/"
let sd = "1960*1080"
let deviceId = "myDeviceid"
let sdItem =  URLQueryItem(name: "sd", value: sd)
let deviceIdItem =  URLQueryItem(name: "device_id", value: deviceId)
components.scheme = scheme
components.host = host
components.path = path
components.queryItems = [sdItem, deviceIdItem]
if let url = components.url {
    print(url.absoluteString)  // https://urldomain.com/livestream_id/?sd=1960*1080&device_id=myDeviceid
}
```

---

To customize the final url you can check if your string contains a keyword and if true just append the query item to the components queryItem property. Something like:

```
let urlString = "urldomain.com/livestream_id/PLAYER_WIDTH&PLAYER_HEIGHT&IDFA_ID&DEVICE_ID"
components.queryItems = []
if urlString.contains("PLAYER_WIDTH&PLAYER_HEIGHT") {
    components.queryItems?.append(sdItem)
}
if urlString.contains("DEVICE_ID") {
    components.queryItems?.append(deviceIdItem)
}
```